# Haml "Illegal Nesting" problem; how to place multiple code elements in the same tag?

Tags: ruby, haml, ruby-on-rails-3

```
- @subjects.each do |s|
  %tr
  %td= s.position
  %td= s.name
  %td= s.visible ? "Yes" : "No"
  %td= s.pages.size
  %td= link_to("Show", {:action => "show", :id => s.id}, :class => "action show") 
    = link_to("Edit", {:action => "edit", :id => s.id}, :class => "action edit")
    = link_to("Delete", {:action => "delete", :id => s.id}, :class => "action delete")
```

error_msg:

> Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %td and nested within it.

I want those three links--show, edit, and delete--in the same td; how can I do it?

Comment: damn,how I can style my code?

Comment: Editing help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help In this case you just need to indent by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just need to change this:

```
%td= link_to("Show", {:action => "show", :id => s.id}, :class => "action show") 
  = link_to("Edit", {:action => "edit", :id => s.id}, :class => "action edit")
  = link_to("Delete", {:action => "delete", :id => s.id}, :class => "action delete")
```

to this:

```
%td
  = link_to("Show", {:action => "show", :id => s.id}, :class => "action show") 
  = link_to("Edit", {:action => "edit", :id => s.id}, :class => "action edit")
  = link_to("Delete", {:action => "delete", :id => s.id}, :class => "action delete")
```

You should also indent the `td`s from the `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I ran into this issue too but the culprit was a trailing space after my `<td>`, which is content for HAML.